# Stop words being broken over 2 lines on command line

Tags: python, text, terminal, raspberry-pi

I am working on a project that randomly selects sentences of less than 280 characters, and then prints them to the command line using a 'typewriter effect'.I am using a raspberry pi and a 7inch touchscreen monitor.

Thanks to help on this forum and other places I have it working. I had issues with words being split over two lines but commenters here have helped me. However, I am still having one issue, when I use

```
    str2 = textwrap.fill(newTok, 20)
```

and then use str2 with this

```
 words = str2 # 
    for char in words:
        sleep(0.1)
        sys.stdout.write(char)
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

The string is been spaced out over 4 lines and takes up full lines.

so instead of

```
This is 
being split 
over four
different lines
```

It is giving

```
This is 
        being split
                    over four 
                              different lines.
```

Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: So… you want to do word wrap?

Comment: Hi @DavisHerring, I guess I do? Not sure is this is possible using sys.stdout but happy to try alternative suggestions?

Comment: Of course it’s possible: you replace certain space characters in your output with newlines (and add newlines after certain hyphens).

Comment: Hey @DavisHerring, thanks for your help but I'm not sure how or where to add newlines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to wrap your strings, just not in the middle of words.

You can use the `textwrap` module. This will make sure your lines are under a certain amount of characters.

```
import textwrap

str1 = "My long strings need to get wrapped at words, not randomly between characters"
str2 = textwrap.fill(str1, 20)
```

So now if you `print(str2)`

```css
My long strings need
to get wrapped at
words, not randomly
between characters
```

Since you seem confused how you line break in general, this is what happens when you `print(repr(str2))`

```
'My long strings need\nto get wrapped at\nwords, not randomly\nbetween characters'
```

The lines break at `\n`

---

To adjust for the new problem that has been edited in, where lines breaks do not return to the left margin, you need to add a carriage return - `\r`

So `str2 = str2.replace('\n', \r\n')`

Comment: Thanks Matt, that makes a lot of sense. I have tried it and it almost works but not exactly - I have updated OP with new issue, any more guidance would be great.

Comment: @heroZero: You need `\r`s for this output device, then; apparently the kernel doesn’t know to do that transformation for you.

Comment: Thanks Davis, a little confused as to where to put /r (carriage return) as with Matt's example  he has print(repr(str2))  but I am using  sys.stdout.write(char)

Comment: to expand, you can try this `words = str2.replace('\n', '\r\n')` instead of your `words = str2`. Or you may possibly need `words = str2.replace('\n', '\r')`

Comment: That's it Matt, much appreciated!