# How to make Python start a new line rather than cutting words off

Tags: python

I'm just using a simple print() function, but when the output hits the end of the window, rather than taking the last word and using it to start a new line, it just continues it in the next line so I have half of the word in one line and the other half in the next line.
For example:

```
print('One of my favourite things to do over the holiday is go snowboarding.')
```

Output:
*One of my favourite things to do over t*|    < this would be the end of the window
*he holiday is to go snowboarding.*

Comment: Check the textwrap module.

Comment: This will be environment specific - what OS and CLI are you targetting?

Comment: Check [Textwrap – Text wrapping and filling in Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/textwrap-text-wrapping-filling-python/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A good way to make long strings wrap to newline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16430200/a-good-way-to-make-long-strings-wrap-to-newline)

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59582463/stop-words-being-broken-over-2-lines-on-command-line

Answer (score 2):

You can use **textwrap** module

```py
import textwrap
strs = "One of my favourite things to do over the holiday is go snowboarding"
print(textwrap.fill(strs, 20))
```

**Output:**
One of my favourite 
things to do over 
the holiday is go
snowboarding

Answer (score 1):

You could write a little alternative print function for this:

```
def print2(text, line_len_limit):
    if len(text) <= line_len_limit:
        print(text)
    else:
        print(text[:line_len_limit])
        return(print2(text[line_len_limit:], line_len_limit)) #recursive call

text = 'One of my favourite things to do over the holiday is go snowboarding.'        
print2(text, 10)
```

Output:

```
One of my 
favourite 
things to 
do over th
e holiday 
is go snow
boarding.
```

If you want to avoid cutting words, then:

```
def print3(text, line_len_limit):
    words = text.split(' ')    
    line = ''
    for i, word in enumerate(words):
        if len(line) + len(word) < line_len_limit:
            line += f'{word} '
        else:
            print(line)
            if len(word) >= line_len_limit:
                print(word)
                return(print3(' '.join(words[i+1:]), line_len_limit))
            return(print3(' '.join(words[i:]), line_len_limit))

print3(text, 10)
```

Output:

```
One of my 
favourite 
things to 
do over 
the 
holiday 
is go 
snowboarding.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.get_terminal_size to query the number of columns in the terminal. It falls back to having 80 columns when python is not attached to a terminal. You can provide this column size as the width arg to https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.fill . `textwrap.fill()` will inject newlines into the string such that no line is longer than the given width, and will only break up words if they are exceptionally long.

```py
import shutil
import textwrap

output = (
    'One of my favourite things to do over the holiday is go snowboarding. '
    'Another sentence to make the string length over 80 characters.'
)

print(textwrap.fill(output, width=shutil.get_terminal_size().columns))
```

Depending on your terminal size, this will produce something like:

```
One of my favourite things to do over the holiday is go snowboarding. Another
sentence to make the string length over 80 characters.
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use new line:

print('One of my favourite things to do over\nthe holiday is go snowboarding.')
note \n within your printed text

or

print("One of my favourite things to do over"+"\n"+"the holiday is go snowboarding.")

Comment: The problem with this is that I'm not sure how large the window will be when my teacher is marking it and I don't want the line to just cut off at random points